# How to always ignore a file (containing a specific line) on git?

Tags: git

In every project of my company, we have a configuration file `config.xml`which contains the text `super_confidential_info` which should not be exposed. The solution is to remove `super_confidential_info`before any commit.

So what I want to do is to avoid to accidentally commit `config.xml` while containing `super_confidential_info`. This is not only true for my current projects, but possibly also all the future projects. Is there any way to setup git to do this?

Comment: Yes, but this will solve the problem only for this project. For all the new projects that I will work on, I will have to remember to add every time `config.xml` to `.gitignore` manually. As you can image @Stavm, this is very error prone.ç

Comment: did you check git hooks ? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I've never heard about git hooks, but from my understanding, I should always add some scripts to `.git/hooks`. I find this solution similar to the one of adding `config.xml`to `.gitignore` everytime.

Comment: A hook like `pre-receive` in the remote repository is much more reliable than `.gitignore`. Local hooks or `.gitignore` could be bypassed more easily on purpose or by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Git's ignoring system based on basic `.gitignore` files (and some configurations) which do not support any kind of conditions. So it's not possible to ignore a file if contains specific content.

This is what you can do:

By using [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) you can search `super_confidential_info` with [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) and if the file contains it you can unstage the file. In this way, you won't commit it accidentally.